# What is the difference between alpine distribution of docker images and latest tag images?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am learning Docker and I am confused as to what is the use of having latest tagged images when we can have alpine distribution images which make it easier to build smaller size custom images and which are themselves downloaded in very less time. My question is why do we need to have so many distributions? Is it related to the extra features that the images provide over one another?

Comment: What do you mean by "distributions"? Alpine Linux is only a single distro of Linux. If you really want small images, you'd use `scratch`, depending on what else you need in the image

Comment: Alpine is very limited and is not compatible with a lot of software. Imagine if you want to base your image on an existing image for some app X and then extend it by installing some software Y on it. If the X software is only available with images based on an alpine base image, and software Y is not compatible with alpine, then you can't achieve what you want, because you won't be able to install software Y since it's not compatible with alpine. If e.g. an Ubuntu version of X was available, you could use it instead as a base. This at-least one reason to offer some variety and not just alpine.